# Is it possible to make transportation card from used cards with nfc function?

Tags: nfc, card

Okay, I am not a expert, so I may not know the concept of nfc at all.

Anyway I have various used credit cards which have nfc chips for transportation.
These cards are expired, but I thought that I could still use the nfc.
So I tried to rewrite the tag and make it into a new transportation card, but I couldn’t.

My question is,

1. How to erase the existing tag on credit card?
2. How to rewrite new transportation tag with a new nfc? I tried to use nfc tool application, but I don’t know the methods.

I searched on the internet a lot, but I couldn’t find the solution. I just don’t want to waste my used card’s nfc chips! :)
I will wait for your wise answers or any kind of help of nfc.

Answer (score 0):

Give up is the answer.

There are so many different types of tags that type used on the credit card will not be compatible with specific transportation NFC type cards like the UK Oyster Card.

The credit card NFC will be read only so not erasable and the chips are not for transportation they just supply your credit card info to a transportation provider so they can charge your credit card for the journey, just as they provide the credit card info to any other contactless terminal in an other shop.